# List files with no linebreaks

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a directory with a bunch of folders in them. I want each folder to create a text file that lists all the files in that folder. The format to list files should look like this:

```
"001.jpg" "002.jpg" "003.jpg" "004.jpg"
```

basically it should list files with no linebreaks. How can I do this with using cmd in windows 7?

Comment: Heh, is there an `xargs` command for Windows? You're not using Powershell, are you?

Comment: This looks more like powershell programming which with your use of windows 7 (which isn't a server OS) means it's probably better asked on [so] or [su].

Comment: Install CygWin and then ask this question again without mentioning Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using only the CMD shell by combining [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (see also: [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)).

#### Steps

1. Create a batch file (e.g., `C:\jpglist.bat`) and save the following instructions to it:

   ```
   @echo off
   if %2 == FALSE exit
   cd /D %1
   for %%a in (*.jpg) do set list=!list! "%%a"
   echo %list:~1%> jpglist.txt
   ```
2. Open a command prompt.
3. Execute

   ```
   forfiles /P PATH /S /C "cmd /V:on /C C:\jpglist.bat @path @isdir"
   ```

   where *PATH* is the full path of the main directory.
4. The batch file is no longer needed. Delete it if you want.

#### How it works

The command:

- `forfiles /P PATH /S /C "..."` goes recursively (`/S`) through *PATH* and its subdirectories and executes `...` for every directory entry.
- `cmd /V:on /C ...` opens a new shell with delayed variable expansion enabled (`/V:on`) and executes `...`.
- `C:\jpglist.bat @path @isdir` calls the batch file and passes the entry's full path as first parameter.

  `@isdir` will be *TRUE* if `@path` is a directory; otherwise, it will be *FALSE*.

The batch file:

- `if %2 == FALSE exit` exits immediately if the first argument is not a directory.
- `cd /D %1` changes to the directory specified in the first argument (`/D` enables switching drives in case it's needed).
- `for %%a in (*.jpg) do set list=!list! "%%a"` goes through all files with a *.jpg* extension and adds their names to the variable *list*.

  Using `!list!` instead of `%list%` delays the variable's expansion, i.e., *list* will get expanded in every iteration, rather then only once at the beginning.
- `echo %list:~1%> jpglist.txt` writes the contents of the variable `list` (except the first character, which will be a leading space) in a file named *jpglist.txt* in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach($_ In Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder\" -Recurse -Directory)
{
    ForEach($file In Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName)
    {
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("$($_.FullName)\crazyList.txt", "`"$($file.Name)`" ", [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
    }
}
```

That outputs a file in each folder with a format exactly as you specified it, with quotation marks.